# Powershell code to check if Azure VM has auto shutdown enabled?

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to check if some Azure VMS have autoshutdown enabled and if it is enabled to disable it. Does anyone know if this can be done with powershell?

Answer (score 1):

you need to do this call to test if it exists:

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceId /subscriptions/{sub_guid}/resourceGroups/{rg_name}/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-{vm_name}
```

if it returns anything you need to delete it:

```
Remove-AzResource -ResourceId /subscriptions/{sub_guid}/resourceGroups/{rg_name}/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-{vm_name}
```

obviously, replace placeholders with real values.

ps. you can use old style cmdlets Get\Remove-AzureRmResource.
pps. you can search my blog for how to create such a schedule with powershell.

Answer (score 0):

With this line you can get all vms in the subscription that has autoshutdown enabled

```
$vmlist = (Get-AzResource -ResourceType microsoft.devtestlab/schedules).ResourceId
```

After that you can loop through the list and remove them